# Global flags and subcommands

Tags: go, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I'm implementing a little CLI with multiple subcommands. I'd like to support global flags, that is flags that apply to all subcommands to avoid repeating them.

For example, in the example below I'm trying to have `-required` flag that is required for all subcommands.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    required = flag.String(
        "required",
        "",
        "required for all commands",
    )
    fooCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("foo", flag.ExitOnError)
    barCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("bar", flag.ExitOnError)
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *required == "" {
        fmt.Println("-required is required for all commands")
    }

    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "foo":
        fooCmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
        fmt.Println("foo")
    case "bar":
        barCmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
        fmt.Println("bar")
    default:
        log.Fatalf("[ERROR] unknown subcommand '%s', see help for more details.", os.Args[1])
    }
}
```

I would expect usage to be like:

```
$ go run main.go foo -required helloworld
```

but if I ran that with the above code I get:

```
$ go run main.go foo -required hello
-required is required for all commands
flag provided but not defined: -required
Usage of foo:
exit status 2
```

It looks like `flag.Parse()` is not capturing `-required` from the CLI, and then the `fooCmd` is complaining that I've given it a flag it doesn't recognize.

What's the easiest way to have subcommands with global flags in Golang?

Comment: Never use `go run main.go`

Comment: @Flimzy not only what Eli said, but also, no explanation? no justification? and is this relevant to the question at hand? :D

Comment: @EliBendersky: I'm sorry if you think my comment was a "flame." The advice is solid.

Comment: @dbzuk: It's not directly related to your question, which is why it's a comment and not an answer. The short explanation for why not: Becuase the unit of compilation in Go is a package, not a file, which typically means all .go files in a directory. It also ignores build tags and other corner cases. `go run main.go` does work sometimes... until it doesn't. And then it's confusing as heck. So best not to get in the habit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you intend to implement subcommands, you shouldn't call [`flag.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Parse).

Instead decide which subcommand to use (as you did with `os.Args[1]`), and call only its [`FlagSet.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet.Parse) method.

Yes, for this to work, all flag sets should contain the common flags. But it's easy to register them once (in one place). Create a package level variable:

```
var (
    required string

    fooCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("foo", flag.ExitOnError)
    barCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("bar", flag.ExitOnError)
)
```

And use a loop to iterate over all flagsets, and register the common flags, pointing to your variable using [`FlagSet.StringVar()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet.StringVar):

```
func setupCommonFlags() {
    for _, fs := range []*flag.FlagSet{fooCmd, barCmd} {
        fs.StringVar(
            &required,
            "required",
            "",
            "required for all commands",
        )
    }
}
```

And in `main()` call `Parse()` of the appropriate flag set, and test `required` afterwards:

```
func main() {
    setupCommonFlags()

    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "foo":
        fooCmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
        fmt.Println("foo")
    case "bar":
        barCmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
        fmt.Println("bar")
    default:
        log.Fatalf("[ERROR] unknown subcommand '%s', see help for more details.", os.Args[1])
    }

    if required == "" {
        fmt.Println("-required is required for all commands")
    }
}
```

You can improve the above solution by creating a map of flag sets, so you can use that map to register common flags, and also to do the parsing.

Full app:

```
var (
    required string

    fooCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("foo", flag.ExitOnError)
    barCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("bar", flag.ExitOnError)
)

var subcommands = map[string]*flag.FlagSet{
    fooCmd.Name(): fooCmd,
    barCmd.Name(): barCmd,
}

func setupCommonFlags() {
    for _, fs := range subcommands {
        fs.StringVar(
            &required,
            "required",
            "",
            "required for all commands",
        )
    }
}

func main() {
    setupCommonFlags()

    cmd := subcommands[os.Args[1]]
    if cmd == nil {
        log.Fatalf("[ERROR] unknown subcommand '%s', see help for more details.", os.Args[1])
    }

    cmd.Parse(os.Args[2:])
    fmt.Println(cmd.Name())

    if required == "" {
        fmt.Println("-required is required for all commands")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put the global flags before the subcommand:

`go run . -required=x foo`.

Use `flag.Args()` instead of `os.Args`:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    required = flag.String(
        "required",
        "",
        "required for all commands",
    )   
    fooCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("foo", flag.ExitOnError)
    barCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("bar", flag.ExitOnError)
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    if *required == "" {
        fmt.Println("-required is required for all commands")
    }   

    args := flag.Args() // everything after the -required flag, e.g. [foo, -foo-flag-1, -foo-flag-2, ...]
    switch args[0] {
    case "foo":
        fooCmd.Parse(args[1:])
        fmt.Println("foo")
    case "bar":
        barCmd.Parse(args[1:])
        fmt.Println("bar")
    default:
        log.Fatalf("[ERROR] unknown subcommand '%s', see help for more details.", args[0])
    }   
}
```

---

If you want to keep all flags together, after the subcommand, write a helper function that adds common flags to each FlagSet:

```
var (
    fooCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("foo", flag.ExitOnError)
    barCmd = flag.NewFlagSet("bar", flag.ExitOnError)
)

type globalOpts struct {
    required string
}

func main() {
    var opts globalOpts

    addGlobalFlags(fooCmd, &opts)
    addGlobalFlags(barCmd, &opts)

    if opts.required == "" {
        fmt.Println("-required is required for all commands")
    } 

    // ...
}

func addGlobalFlags(fs *flag.FlagSet, opts *globalOpts) {
    fs.StringVar(
        &opts.required,
        "required",
        "",
        "required for all commands",
    )
}
```

Perhaps you can also combine the two approaches to make the global flags work in any position.

Comment: Calling flag.Parse will fail if the subcommands contain flags.

Comment: @Vser, no, it does not because ["Flag parsing stops just before the first non-flag argument"](https://pkg.go.dev/flag#hdr-Command_line_flag_syntax): https://go.dev/play/p/qRPEg-eQf5I

Comment: I discovered it myself and thought it was a relevant addition to the answer as it is not obvious from the first sight. But your comment with the appropriate references is even more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would be interested in using https://github.com/spf13/cobra - it supports exactly this usecase and many others.